# Is the use of a div between table rows allowed?

Tags: html, html-table

I am creating a table and need to put a div inside it. Is the use of a div inside a table like below allowed?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>

<div class="files">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</div>

   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sure this isn't permitted, as it doesn't even make sense. What would you expect this to do?

Comment: so this is oke? `<tr><div class="files"><td></td><td></td></div></tr>`

Comment: If you will explain your goal, it would be a lot easier for us to offer a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Tables can only contain rows. You can use two tables, or put a div inside of a td or th. If you just want to apply your "files" class, you can do that directly on the row. If you really want separated sections in the same table, then add a special "table-separator" class to the boundary rows with styling on that class to space them apart.

Comment: Tables can contain much more than rows. They may contian `td`, `tr`, `thead` or `tbody`, `tfoot`, `col`, `colgroup` and `caption` elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. The other tags (thead, colgroup, etc.) are for providing more information about the table itself, not for actually containing table data like divs. The actual contents of the table have to go within a row (tr). The rows themselves can only contain cells. That's literally what  table is -- a set of rows that contain cells. The only sensible place to put divs is inside a td or th.

Comment: You say "Tables can contain only rows." This is a plainly false statement. That's what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `div`, use `tbody` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody), It's only valid to put your `div` between `table`s or to put your `div` inside the `td` (or `th`) element (which is probably a bad idea). All of the following is valid:

```
<table>
   <tbody class="files">
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="files">
</div>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <div class="files">
          </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at

this works:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td> 
         <div>This will work.</div> 
      </td>
   </tr>
<table>
```

this does not work:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <div> this does not work. </div> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

nor does this work:

```
<table>
  <div> this does not work. </div>
</table>
```